# Is there a way to remember(store) the return type of decltype?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype, boost-any

I am storing the return values of a function call like this in a std::vector:

This is a very rough estimate

```
std::vector<boost::any> pressures;

Printer printerObs1;
Printer printerObs2;

const int initialPressure = 1;

auto pressure = MakeSubject<Pressure>(
                    BindObservers(printerObs1, printerObs2), initialPressure);//Return type Pressure<Printer, Printer> if I had passed three observers, the return type would have been Pressure<Printer, Printer, Printer> and so on

pressures.push_back(pressure); // This forgets the type.
```

If pressure were still in scope, I could easily say:

```
decltype(pressure) *p = boost::any_cast<decltype(pressure)>(&pressures[0]);

p->Change(1999); //class Pressure has a function called Change.
```

The question is, how do I remember the type of an auto that has been stored in an

```
std::vector<boost::any>
```

? AFAIK, decltype doesn't even return a value that can be stored?

**So I need a container that can store a boost::any __and__ remember it's decltype** so that I can say (this doesn't work but it is the essence of what I am trying to achieve)

```
decltype(pressures[0]) *p = boost::any_cast<decltype(pressures[0])>(&pressures[0]);
```

Comment: [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/any.html) always remembers the stored type, if that's what you are trying to ask about... If not, clarify your question please.

Comment: Really? How do I get it?

Comment: member `type` gives you the `std::typeinfo`.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting the analogy with decltype. How do I make us std::typeinfo to say the equivalent of   decltype(pressure) *p = boost::any_cast(&pressure[0]);

Comment: `decltype` is for getting the type of an expression. That is a pure compile-time construct. `typeid` is for getting the `std::typeinfo` corresponding to a type, which is actually still existing at runtime. So now I think you want to do full dynamic typing. But C++ is statically typed!

Comment: Ugh, got it. I need the compile time information. Otherwise I can't call the function Change because  MakeSubject<Pressure> returns either Pressure<Printer> or Pressure<Printer, Printer> or Pressure<Printer, Printer, Printer> etc...

Comment: If decltype can get it, why can't I store the value the compiler has at hand when I call decltype? boost::any forgets the type probably by storing void * or something like it.

Comment: Deduplicator already pointed out that `decltype` is purely compile-time. `decltype(<anything>) *p = <expression>;` cannot depend in any way on the dynamic type of `<expression>`, since that dynamic type will not and cannot be known at compile-time, only at run-time. You can't make the compiler store it somewhere and load it later, since storing and loading are run-time actions, not compile-time actions.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079755/restoring-any-type

Answer (score 1):

When you put a variable into an heterogeneous container it's type is gone and will never come back. You can try to reconstruct it's type and apply different operations according to it, but you will never be able to declare a variable with the initial type or a function that returns that type, not with the current C++ standard.

Here are a couple of *awful* ways to proceed without changing your design:

1. Whenever you store value in `pressures`, store its `typeid` in a corresponding vector, then switch on the `typeid` to apply the correct operation when you process the pressures vector.
2. ...or, if you don't want an extra vector, you can exploit the type info stored in `boost::any` with a set of `any_cast` until you find the correct one.

You will have to place the switch statement into a block that does some standard thing for each case (like printing something, returning a string, ...). Note that both these methods will require you to know a pool of possible types; this makes `boost::variant` a better candidate. **So my actual advice is to review the design: storing different `boost::any` in a container is very rarely a good idea.**